# Local server works from duckdns but just in locak network

Tags: networking, router, dns, webserver, dynamic-dns

I've put a local web server in my local Windows 10 desktop machine. I've also setup a dynamic DNS using duckdns.org. Now if I try to connect to it from my mobile phone using *myserver.duckdns.org* and I'm connected to my local wifi network, everything works fine. I believe that it means that:

1. My current IP is correctly set at duckdns.
2. My router port is correctly forwarding to my machine.
3. My machine firewall is open to connections from my router.

It is https server, so I forwarded the port 443 to 8888. I don't know if it matters.

But if I turn off the wifi and try to connect, I got a connection timeout. How do I fix it?

Comment: I believe https would be 443 & 8443 by default. Go to canyouseeme.org and verify the ports are open outside your network.

Answer (score 0):

Ops, there is just one explanation: my isp blocks all the default ports, even 443 :-(.